# Dynamics Crm apply filter on expand

Tags: php, api, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-webapi

Need to apply filter in expand query.Requirement is search primary contacts of account by yomi full name.

If any way to identify the primary contacts in contact entity.

URl:

```
/accounts?$expand=primarycontactid($select=contactid,fullname)&$top=3
```

Expected Is:

```
 If search name is john then contact having fullname john only get listed.
```

Tried:

```
/accounts?$expand=primarycontactid($select=contactid,fullname&$filter=contains(yomifullname,%27'. $key .'%27))&$top=3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use semicolon `;` in between clauses like `$expand=primarycontactid($select=contactid,fullname;$filter=contains(yomifullname,'arun'))`

Try this:

```
https://crmdev.crm.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.0/accounts?$select=accountid,accountnumber,name&$expand=primarycontactid($select=contactid,fullname;$filter=contains(yomifullname,'arun'))&$top=3
```

[Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/common-data-service/webapi/retrieve-entity-using-web-api#options-to-apply-to-expanded-entities)